# Yii2 vendor url for registerCssFile

Tags: php, url, yii, yii2, vendor

I'm try to make a Yii2 extension and just want to register a css file from extension folder.

Css file directory is:`project_folder\vendor\extension-ven\extension-name\assets\css\main.css`

I must be use registerCssFile function.

```
public void registerCssFile ( $url, $options = [], $key = null )
```

What am i must be write to url in registerCssFile function. I can't use alias  `Yii::getAlias('@vendor/extension-ven/extension-name/assets/css/main.css');`

Is there any method am i use like alias but give me a vendor url?

Thanks

Comment: Can u please clarify - are you trying to build an extension of your own or are you trying to use a 3rd-party extension?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to do it is:

1. Prepare `Asset` class with the `js` and `css` files for the extension. [Example here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/assets/AppAsset.php).
2. Inside add `sourcePath` property pointing the assets folder (remove `basePath` and `baseUrl` properties).

   ```
   public $sourcePath = '@vendor/extension-ven/extension-name/assets';
   ```
3. In your extension class register your `Asset` class (i.e. if this is `Widget` you can do it in the `run()` method; this assumes your extension implements `ViewContextInterface` interface like `Widget` class).

   ```
   YourAssetName::register($this->view);
   ```
4. All the asset files are automatically copied from the source folder to the `assets` folder in the public `web` folder when extension is called.

Comment: That's the way to go. Only a couple of things - assuming the extension is a widget then his extension class should technically extend from `yii\base\Widget` class rather then `Component` class. Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-widgets.html#creating-widgets Also to register the assets we should be using `$this->getView()` instead of `$this->view`. So the correct call to register assets would be `YourAssetName::register($this->getView());`

Comment: @sm1979 `Widget` extends `Component` so extending `Widget` extends `Component` as well but I should change my answer about `Component` and replace it with `ViewContextInterface`. And because it extends `Component` you can use `$this->view` instead of `$this->getView()` (it's the same anyway).